# Why is the camera view pink in Unity 5?

Tags: unity

I am a beginner. I created a 3D project with a cube object, and I am getting this pink display, in the camera view.

[image: Camera view in Unity 5]

Why is the camera view pink?

Comment: It seems likely it has to do with that cube in the way, but could it be a missing skybox?

Comment: Could you post a screen shot of your scene view, so we can see where the cube is in relation to the camera? Also if you could show the inspector view for the camera, that would be really useful as well :-)

Comment: Which version of Unity do you have installed? I am facing the same problem [(no cube in front or behind the camera), whole new project is PINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gpyb.jpg). I am facing this problem since the beginning and because of this I can't build any other Unity projects I downloaded from Unity examples.

Comment: @GamesWarehouse4u the pink colour means Unity had some kind of problem compiling and using the shader programs used to draw materials or backgrounds in the viewport. There are a lot of potential causes for this - from errors accessing the shader files to errors communicating with your graphics driver. Try reinstalling the drivers for your graphics card, and then reinstalling Unity from scratch. If you're using a bleeding-edge/experimental version, try falling back to the last stable version to see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have created a cube as a child of the camera, thus taking up the entire view port. Imagine placing a thumb in front of a camera's lens. Since the cube's material is pink (you seem to have deleted the default material), all you see is one side of a giant pink cube.

You can either:

- Change the hierarchy of the cube. Click on the cube, hold the click, and drag it *outside* of Main Camera.
- Set the Camera's "Near Clipping Pane" property to a different value, superior to 1 (which seems to be the depth of the cube).

Comment: I have changed it as you said. The camera view is still pink. :(

Comment: @Warda does changing the "X" Rotation on the Main Camera's Transform produce any effect? If you select the Main Camera from the Scene tab, does the Camera Preview still shows only pink? Have you tried deleting the cube altogether? What Unity version are you using? Could you try creating a new empty project and seeing if it works as intended?

Comment: I created a new scene. It still gives me pink camera view. [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ep0rlBQRcVc&t=182s)  I'm following. The person has the camera view brown and the sunset. I am not having this.. why? help me, please.

Comment: I'm using Unity 5. Yes, if I select the Main Camera front from the scene tab, still pink. I tried a new project thrice.. IDK, what's happening...

Comment: @Warda the person in the tutorial deletes everything from the scene, but then imports a custom package with his project. Have you followed those steps as well? You can always try to follow one of Unity's official tutorials. The one I recommend for starters is [this one](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! Is there any problem with my Graphic card. My system using DX11.

Comment: I followed every step he told in his video. The problem occurs just pink screen :(

Comment: I see a problem with *both* solutions (@Warda, this suggests why you have not found a solution); A: changing the hierarchy of the cube *literally does nothing* for why you describe this as the problem. In doing so, the actual position *value* of the cube will change (to reflect its position relative to *world*, instead of *camera*), but the cube will remain *exactly where it is*. B: yeah, OK. this technically might *fix* the problem; by changing the camera view so it *can't see* the problem. Would be a real shame if that camera had to see other things, though. Like the game.

Comment: Also, as I have just confirmed, a camera inside a cube looking out does not see the cube (given that all the facing normals point away from the camera). This seems further supported by the fact that the cubes mesh renderer appears *disabled* in the screenshot.

Comment: @Franconstein Thanks for helping. I just installed another version of unity. And it works fine. [Unity view](http://imgur.com/a/LK13X)

Comment: @Warda I'm glad you were able to solve this unusual problem!

Answer (score 2):

What you see is a *default material*. It is nothing to be overly concerned about; it serves as a *placeholder*. The only problem appears to be the *colour*; In my experience, the default material is usually a light grey. In the recent version of Unity I downloaded, version 5.5.0f3, it is black.

If you wish to try resetting your default material colour, [I found other users who have experienced similar issues](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/981464/unity-5-default-shaders-are-pink.html), on *installing* Unity. One user has found a solution, which seems to work, most of the time:

> **Answer** by [Javier_8](http://answers.unity3d.com/users/454637/javier-8.html) · Jun 23, 2015 at 10:59 PM
>   I fixed it.
>   Edit->Preferences->GI Cache->[Clear Cache]
>   <sub>[- "Unity 5 default shaders are pink" @ Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/981464/unity-5-default-shaders-are-pink.html)</sub>

Remember that this is the *default material*. Pink or not, you should still aim to replace this material at your earliest convenience, if only to a more suitable prototype material. My recommendation would be to simply *ignore* the pink; pink is far more noticeable than grey, making it much easier to tell if a particular mesh needs an actual material. [You can find information on creating and making materials at the Unity manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html).

---

As for *what* is being displayed, I can only speculate, given the information that has been provided.

First and foremost, *it is not the cube*. We know this for *two* reasons:

1. In the inspector, your cube has its `MeshRenderer` disabled. This is the part that *renders* the mesh of the cube. While disabled, your cube is not rendering, and you will not be able to see it from the game view.

[image: Disabling the "Mesh Renderer" on an object makes it invisible to the game camera.]

2. From the inside of a cube, all normals (values that tell us the *facing direction* of each face) face *away* from the camera. When a normal faces *away* from you, the face does not render, *even when the `MeshRenderer` is enabled*, as you can see in the following animation.

[image: The default camera does not render faces from the "inside"; from the inside, the cube is invisible, even when it would otherwise be visible.]

Given that the only other object in the scene is a directional light, I would speculate that it is the *Clear Flags* setting, on your camera. You might have this set to *Skybox*, with the default shader interfering with the default skybox. It is entirely possible that you might simply have it set to *Clear Colour*, and actually have the colour manually set to pink.

[image: Changing the camera "Clear Flags" value to "Solid Colour" has a similar effect.]

Comment: Firstly, I respect your answer. I have still had the same problem. The issue is not a cube. When I Press Game tab, it shows me pink with setting the Clear Flag as Skybox. Now, I couldn't get this?? :(

Comment: Have a look at my again pink screen. [Game tab](http://imgur.com/a/jYMHN)

Comment: @Warda, as I said, the only other explanation I could give would be the actual Skybox  having the same issues. Did you reset your GI Cache?

Comment: Yes, I reset the GI Cache.

Comment: @Warda, you havnt saved a build of your project, have you?

Comment: I saved it but didn't build.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I just installed another version of unity. And it works fine. [Unity view](http://imgur.com/a/LK13X)

Comment: How did you make that screen recording?